# Repo init can not succeed because of GnuTLS error

Tags: android, git, ssl, repository, gnutls

I want to get the source code of Android. To browse some blogs in the Internet, "repo init" is recommended.

Then I use it, but it is impossible because of the following error.

```
android@ubuntu]~/WORKING_DIRECOTRY$ repo init -u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
error:GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received while accessing  https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal:HTTP request failed
```

I wrote the Android source URL after "repo init -u", but I could not write the URL 
because this site tell me that new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be from the Version of Repo that you are using from The Google gerrit source. 1.18 is what I am using now.

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Google recommends that you use 10.04 or 10.10

Try to resync your /bin/repo binary and your Python install.

```
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
```

I know that if I added repo to just my local .bashrc PATH it gave me problems compared to adding it to the /etc/bash.bashrc

```
sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc 

Adding this to the bottom: 
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

For the Setup, they also forgot this little bundle (which you will need to compile with)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6 /usr/lib32/libX11.so
```

Some more information on your Environment and the Libs installed would be helpful.